# Generating ActiveX Command Buttons and assigning code to them externally in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, activex, commandbutton, programmatically-created

I'm working on a task where it needs to generate ActiveX Command Buttons dynamically and assign certain code to them automatically. Each time I close the Worksheet, the command button needs to be deleted (it is completed), but code for that button remains.

So I'm trying to find code which will assign a code to the command button while checking if same sub exists, if it exists then delete it and create new sub with same name having the code I need.

My code is

```
Public WS As Worksheet


Sub MyButton()

Dim j, p, q As Integer
Dim ShButton As OLEObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim Code As String

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

j = 0
p = 1
q = 3

For j = 29 To WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = WS.Range("C" & j)

    Set ShButton = WS.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
            Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.RowHeight * 3 / 4)
    
    WS.OLEObjects("CommandButton" & q).Object.Caption = "My Button " & p
    WS.OLEObjects("CommandButton" & q).Object.WordWrap = True
    
    
    ' ##Need code to Check Duplicate sub and delete it if exists

    Code = ""
    Code = "Private Sub CommandButton" & q & "_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "MsgBox " & Chr(34) & "Worksheet name is " & Chr(34) & " & ActiveSheet.Name" & vbCrLf  ' ##Demo Code
    Code = Code & "End Sub"
    Debug.Print Code
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Sheet1").CodeName).CodeModule
        .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With
    
    
    
    
    p = p + 1
    q = q + 1
Next j

End Sub
```

OR **Simply to add a code to command button programmatically and delete the previous same name code** will do also

Comment: Do you really need an ActiveX-Button? I find it easier to use Shapes, for those it is easy to assign code (use the `OnAction`-method). Anyhow, instead of always creating a new button, you could also just hide it if it is not needed:  `WS.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").visible = False`.

Comment: How to use shapes to assign code? Is it Form button? and for hiding the buttons, no. of buttons change every time based on the range, So it becomes problem while adding new button and naming it if last button name/ number is dynamic.

Comment: No, any simple shape (Insert->Shape), or you can use also an image. To assign code, simply right click on it and select "Assign Macro". Or, as I said, assign a Subroutine via code by writing the name of a subroutine to the `OnAction`-property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @funthomas for your suggestion. As per your suggestion, I've tried adding simple button and `OnAction` Command to it, and it simplified my code also (I no longer needed to create new sub for this)

I'll share the code I've modified

```
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrFile)
    strtRow = 29
    Set ParamWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' My other code is here to print data starting from Row 29(each row in each loop)

    Set rng = ParamWS.Range("C" & strtRow)
    p = strtRow - 28
    Set ShButton = ParamWS.Buttons.Add(Left:=43.5, Top:=rng.Top + 10, Width:=92, Height:=46)

    With ShButton
      .OnAction = "Module3.create_sheetFromButton"
      .Caption = "Single Button" & p
      .Name = strtRow
    End With

    strtRow = strtRow + 1

   Next i
```

I'm deleting all the buttons at the end of my main code, also I'm not creating any new sub for buttons (Thanks to the suggestion of `OnAction`), so I don't need to check for duplicate sub.